# Filter elements in PropertyGrid

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, propertygrid

In System.Windows.Forms there are a PropertyGrid that displays properties of an attached object. Let's say `MyTextBox : TextBox`.

Now, I would like to display on it some MyTextBox properties, say only `Size`, `Location` and my custom property `Date`.

More that than, I would like to be able to change the real property names, say "Dimension", "Location" and "Starting Date".

I saw two projects on this subject : [first](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FilteredPropertyGrid.aspx?msg=3456198#xx3456198xx) and [second](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/bending_property.aspx), but first does not work well(for browsable properties), and the second seems to add an event for each property changes, this is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hide them with a `[Browsable(false)]` attribute.  If you want to change the name, you need to write your own TypeDescriptor as seen [here](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/26/how-do-i-display-property-names-in-the-property-grid-that-are-different-from-the-actual-property-names-in-the-class.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but I wrote about a TextBox. I can't override all TextBox's properties with Browsablefalse attribute.

Comment: My fault... I totally overlooked the base class.  You can use the same technique in the CustomTypeDescriptor I listed to filter out the properties you want as well as change their names.

Comment: same technique (?).. hmm.. I tried the code it don't compile (undefined method GetFriendlyname in FriendlyNamePropertyDescriptor class) marked: "// replace with code to return a friendly name"  but what should I replace there?

Comment: That's where your code would go to say "if this property is called Size, call it Dimension instead."  As far as "same technique" I mean in the ICustomTypeDescriptor GetProperties method implementation, you can filter out the properties that you want to return.

Comment: so..., as I understand, I need a method with a big if else for each property name and its DisplayName... so this solution will not be universal, but for a component... maybe..

Comment: Well, there is a "DisplayName" attribute that you could use, but you would then need to decorate every property.  So, yeah, this is component specific.